# Вставить картинки в проект javafx

Tags: java, javafx, url

В своем приложении javafx, который я создаю в IDE IntelliJ IDEA, мне нужно добавить картинки. Для заливки фигуры, фон и т.д. Проблема в том, что я ни как не пойму, какую ссылку на картинку нужно указывать.
Если я кладу все необходимые ресурсы в src [image: структура проекта]

и пишу такой код:

```
Image img = new Image(getClass().getResource("watch.png").toExternalForm());
```

, то программа не компилируется. 
Если же я беру абсолютный путь, перенеся картинку в браузер, так:

```
Image img = new Image("file:///C:/Users/Annelig/Downloads/Watch/HW1_module3/Watch/src/watch.png");
```

то все работает, но естественно только на том компьютере, на котором я создавал проект. 
Подскажите, как мне вставить картинки, так чтобы они открывались на других компьютерах? Заранее спасибо за советы.

Comment: И ошибка компиляции какая-то есть?

Comment: @Anton да, там просто много картинок и внутренних вызовов, думаю не имеет смысла сюда кидать этот вывод. Но ошибка именно из-за картинок

Comment: И никто не угадает какая у Вас ошибка и как ее исправить. [mcve]

Comment: @Anton я создал простой пример, где добавил только одну картинку. Прога бросает NullPointerException на строке, где добавляется ImageView в root:
Image img = new Image(getClass().getResource("denis.png").toExternalForm());
        ImageView imgView  = new ImageView(img);
        root.getChildren().addAll(imgView);

Answer (score 1):

(Ваш проект наверное watch, вы замазали самую верхнюю строку синим цветом) Укажите путь от проекта

```
Image img = new Image("src/watch.png"); //ваш случай
```

Если не сработает, то поместите файл в проект из src

Answer (score 1):

У меня сработало так:
1) создать директорию ( package) в src, я назвал images. 
2) положить туда картинки
3) в коде писать:
Image img = new Image ("/images/название_картинки");[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

И так сойдет:

```
Image img = new Image(getClass().getResource("../watch.png").toExternalForm());
```